# Error converting double* to double(*)

Tags: c++, fftw

The following code is supposed to return the fft of a sinusoidal signal using fftw3 library:

```
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <time.h>
# include <fftw3.h>
# include <iostream>
# include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
   int i;
   const int N=256;
   double Fs=1000;//sampling frequency
   double T=1/Fs;//sample time 
   double f=500;//frequency
   double *in;
   fftw_complex *out;

   double t[N-1];//time vector 
   fftw_plan plan_forward;

   in = (double*) fftw_malloc( sizeof( double ) * N );
   out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc( sizeof( fftw_complex ) * N );

   for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
   {
     t[i] = i*T;
     in[i] = 0.7 *sin(2*M_PI*f*t[i]);// generate sine waveform
   }

   plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_1d ( N, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE );

   fftw_execute ( plan_forward );

   printf ( "\n" );
   printf ( "  Output FFT Coefficients:\n" );
   printf ( "\n" );

   for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
   {
     printf ( "  %3d  %12f  %12f\n", i, out[i][0], out[i][1] );
   }
   fftw_destroy_plan ( plan_forward );
   fftw_free ( in );
   fftw_free ( out );
   return 0;
 }
```

The error I am getting is cannot convert `‘double*’ to ‘double (*)[2]` for argument 2 in `fftw_plan` function.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Line # of error, and full signature of functions you're trying to call?

Comment: cannot convert ‘double*’ to ‘double (*)[2]’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘fftw_plan_s* fftw_plan_dft_1d(int, double (*)[2], double (*)[2], int, unsigned int)’
 plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_1d ( N, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was to change the function `fftw_plan_dft_1d`  to  `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d`.

Answer (score 3):

The `in` variable also needs to be `fftw_complex *`, not `double *`.  FFTW's complex data type happens to be `double[2]`, hence the error message: The compiler expects a pointer to `double[2]`, but you are passing in a pointer to `double`.

Comment: [Tutorial](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs.html#Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs) for this function shows  the proper declaration.

Comment: I changed it but now the error I get is :error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘double’ to ‘fftw_complex {aka double [2]}’
  in[i] =0.7 *sin(2*M_PI*f*t[i]);// generate sine waveform

Comment: I am trying to apply FFT to real 1D data. So how come the in variable also needs to be fftw_complex * ??

Comment: Read up on [`fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d`](http://www.fftw.org/doc/One_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html#One_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data).  That function is for real data.

Comment: @Sven, I'll stop hijacking your answer now :-)

Comment: @Carlton..LoL..Thank you guys. All I had to do was to change fftw_plan_dft_1d to fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d. It is working now.